How to get the IQN of a Storage Device for ISCI Configuration for an openshift cluster
I have a small baremetal openshift cluster and want to use ISCSI for creating and using PVs. As far as the documentation went i have activated and set up ISCSI on the worker nodes and configured it with the IQN and Storage Mapping on the hosts on a Pure Storage Array.
But i am still missing the IQN for the Storage device to create a PV.
I followed all the steps  until i got to this passage of the documentation of openshift.text
As you can see i need to get the iqn of the storage :
 iqn: iqn.2014-12.example.server:storage.target00

But i cannot find out where i get this IQN. At least on purestorage it seems that only Hosts have IQNs at all.
In every Thread for this topic i found so far there is only ever talked about the iqn of the hosts which i already have.

After some searching i found this in the pure storage documentation: iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p . Which shows me the IQN i should need.

It was exactly as easy as i already have commented. I just needed to login on the Hosts and use:  iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p . Than i had to put in the IQN i get into the PV i wanted to create like this with multiple targets and the LUN from the Storage:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: iscsi-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  iscsi:
    targetPortal: 10.0.0.1:3260
    portals: ['10.0.2.16:3260', '10.0.2.17:3260', '10.0.2.18:3260'] 
    iqn: iqn.2016-04.test.com:storage.target00
    lun: 0
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: false

